# Citing inside the cell of flextable

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, flextable

I'm trying to create a table with rmarkdown and flextable where I am citing various works.

my Rmakrdown file:

````
---
title: "Innovative title"
author: "Vag Vaf"
date: '2021-12-29'
bibliography: references.bib
csl: apa-6th-edition.csl
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    citation_package: natbib
    keep_tex: true
    extra_dependencies: rotating, bookmark
  fontsize: 12pt
  geometry: margin=1in
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.retina = 3, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```

```{r studies-table}
studies.table <- tibble (
  Authors = c("@Author1",
              "@Author2"),
  Area = c("Area1",
           "Area2")
    )
ft <- flextable(studies.table)
```
````

in my references.bib:

```
@article{Author1,
author = {Author, Solo},
journal = {Journal of Reproducible Examples},
pages = {1--18},
title = {{Yet another Test Title}},
volume = {1},
year = {2022}
}
@article{Author2,
author = {Author, Two and Author, Four},
journal = {Journal of Reproducible Examples},
pages = {75--82},
title = {{Awesome title}},
volume = {1},
year = {2022}
}
```

I am trying with this code, but @Author1 and @Author2 are not converted to the actual citation. They are displayed as `@Aurthor1` and `@Author2` in the table. Is there any way to indicate that this should be converted to a citation?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example (including the citations)?

Comment: @Maël: updated as per request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `ftExtra` is required for markdown syntaxes work in flextable cells:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(easypackages)
packages(
  "tidyverse",
  "flextable",
  "ftExtra"
)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.retina = 3, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```

```{r studies-table}
studies.table <- tibble(
  Authors = c(
    "@Author1",
    "@Author2"
  ),
  Area = c(
    "Area1",
    "Area2"
  )
)
flextable(studies.table) %>%
  ftExtra::colformat_md()
```
````

[image: answer result]